# How to check if view result is empty Twig

Tags: 8, theming

To check the field I use the following code:

```
{% if content.field_name|render is empty %}
```

How to check on node.twig if `{{ my_cool_view }}` result is empty? Is this generally possible in Drupal 8? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [twig_tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) Module, and use `drupal_view_result` extension like:

```
{% if drupal_view_result('who_s_new', 'block_1') is empty %}
```

For more info look at this module [Cheat sheet](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/cheat-sheet-8x-2x)

Comment: Extra tip: you can add argument too, like drupal_view_result('who_s_new', 'block_1', 'all'), this is useful if you render with argument elsewhere the check is wrong